# Dynamic Menu Item

Tags: posts, customization, menus

I'm a complete WordPress n00b, so your guidance is very much appreciated. Long story short I am running a theme with a child theme attached.

I need a function that will retrieve my site's latest post and format it so it can be used as a menu item. The function will need to collect the post's link, heading and thumbnail/featured image.

From there, perhaps I could create a Custom Link, insert #customurl and #customtext into the relevant fields and then have the function replace them with dynamic values. I've found a function that grabs the latest post's URL, but I need a little more than that.

Could you help me out? Thank you!

Comment: It is not clear enough what kind of help you want to get.

Comment: I need a function that will retrieve my site's latest post and format it so it can be used as a menu item. The function will need to collect the post's link, heading and thumbnail/featured image.

Comment: Your post and comment look like you make a job offer for function development. I'm not sure it responds to rules.